# FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() is not logging the user out

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

EDIT: figured it out, it was just a stupid extra close tag in the HTML.

I made a jQuery script that turns my login button into a button that should log the user out using Firebase. Everything else works except that clicking on it does not log the user out.

There are similar questions on StackOverflow but they are about Angular and Android environments.

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
  ...
    $("#login-button").click(function() {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    });
  }

});
```

There are no error messages anywhere I can find. The user remains logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an extra close tag in the HTML